# Greenplum Database: Segment data directory does not exist

Tags: database, postgresql, database-administration, greenplum, segment

I am getting below error during Greenplum database initialisation step. Using 3 hosts including primary host and two segment without a standby primary. 3 segments folders already existing in both of the segment nodes. 2 segments from node1 is started but 1 failed, for node 2 all three failed. What I am missing?

20231018:11:24:38:016792 gpstart:localhost:gpadmin-[INFO]:-DBID:5  FAILED  host:'localhost.localdomain' datadir:'/data2/primary/gpseg3' with reason:'Segment data directory does not exist for: '/data2/primary/gpseg3''
20231018:11:24:38:016792 gpstart:localhost:gpadmin-[INFO]:-DBID:6  FAILED  host:'localhost.localdomain' datadir:'/data2/primary/gpseg4' with reason:'Segment data directory does not exist for: '/data2/primary/gpseg4''
20231018:11:24:38:016792 gpstart:localhost:gpadmin-[INFO]:-DBID:7  FAILED  host:'localhost.localdomain' datadir:'/data2/primary/gpseg5' with reason:'Segment data directory does not exist for: '/data2/primary/gpseg5''
20231018:11:24:38:016792 gpstart:localhost:gpadmin-[INFO]:-DBID:2  FAILED  host:'localhost.localdomain' datadir:'/data1/primary/gpseg0' with reason:'PG_CTL failed.'

I tried reinitialisation after cleaning segment directories but no lock.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick guess without seeing your directory structure or your initialization template file,  did you create all the directories under /data1/primary ?

Did you create directories under /data2/primary as well?

Comment: Each node 3 segment directory created by GP itself, i didn't create it manually. I mean the segment allocation is successful but segment starting is not.

Comment: I figured out one thing all my VMs were using same host name as localhost later I changed but still have the same error.